# Jquery .text() concatenates instead of replaces

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I have the following piece of code:

```
var customer = $('#customer');

customer.on('change', function(){
    var dom = $(customer.find('option'));
    var txt = dom.text();

    $('#settingsoption1label').show().find('span.mdl-radio__label').text(txt);
});
```

Whenever I change `#customer` dropdown which is using the Select2 plugin, then the text from the `customer` element concatenates instead of replaces. I also tried adding `empty()` or `html('')` but nothing so far seems to work. I want the string to be replaced with the selected value instead of concatenated. Right now, when I change the dropdown, the value of the dropdown just adds to the end of the `span` element.

**edit**

Here's my HTML. I'm using Laravel.

```
<div class="form-group" >
    @if(Auth::user()->is(3) || Auth::user()->is(1))
    <label for="customer">Klant<br></label>
    <select id="customer" name="customer" class="searchselect searchselectstyle searchgroup1">
        @if(Request::old('customer') != NULL)
            <option value="{{Request::old('customer')}}">{{$customers->where('id', intval(Request::old('customer')))->first()->name}}</option>
        @endif
    </select>
    @endif
</div>
```

Comment: please show your html

Comment: Please post a functional example that illustrates your problem on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/): ...The result of the .text() method is a string containing the combined text of all matched elements. ....

So, you may try to get only the selected option:

```
    var customer = $('#customer');

    customer.on('change', function(){
        var dom = customer.find('option:selected');
        var txt = dom.text();

        $('#settingsoption1label').show().find('span.mdl-radio__label').text(txt);
    });
```